# First Post Audit for bad answer... what to do about all the other similar ones still there?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, not-an-answer, first-post-review

I recently completed (successfully) [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21769199). The answer was pretty low quality, so I can see why it was flagged. But, when I went to the rest of the answers on the question there were quite a few more that were equally bad yet did not get flagged.

I flagged a couple of them as Not an Answer, but I want to know if there was a better category to flag them under, or if I should have just left them alone. It seems contradictory to just leave them be after all this time when an audit revealed the very same problem on the very same question.

What is the verdict? Do we leave these be, or flag as NAA?

Comment: The answer in your audit looks OK to me. I'm guessing someone saw "I also had this problem" by a 1-rep user and flagged it, despite the fact that the answer does describe a possible solution. Not a great or well-worded answer, but an answer nonetheless.

Comment: Does it need to be removed from the audit que then?

Answer (score 9):

Are they really "not answers" or are they just bad answers?

If they aren't answers, then flag them.

If they are answers, but bad ones, then down-vote them.

I took a quick look and most of them do look like attempts at answering the question, but are poor quality, so you should be down-voting, not flagging.

Comment: Yeah, but the same could be said for the one that ended up in the audit que. It made an attempt to answer, but a poor quality one. So either that one was inappropriately flagged, or these need to also be flagged. At least that was my line of thinking... that's why I brought the question here.

Comment: @SandPiper it's quite possible that the one in the audit queue was incorrectly flagged in the first place.

Comment: Does it need to be removed from the audit que then?